# Is Unity3D  a good choice for creating an interactive human avatar? 

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, java-3d

I am a part of research team that researches some aspects of human body movements. I have to choose the proper technology for creating an interactive human avatar which will test/illustrate some research points. The resulting program should run on many platforms: iPhone/iPad, Android phones, PC, Mac and XBox (interacting with Kinect).

The most close existing 3D technology that I found is Unity , but having no experience with it I am afraid it is a significant overhead for creating a simple interactive human avatar that can take different poses (no faces, no textures, pure geometry).

My second thought was Java3d, but it seems abandoned by Oracle.

Which other options should I check?

**I know that similar questions were asked on SO, but things are changing, new technologies arise almost daily and 2 years old answer can be absolutely irrelevant.**

Comment: Adobe AIR probably has most coverage of the platforms you list, but you'll still need to build a native extension for use with kinect. It might be better to abstract your code base well enough so you can easily port/adapt it to specific platforms...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to modelling, Unity3D isn't the best choice. You don't have much to work with... just a few primitive 3D shapes (cubes, spheres and a few more) which you can "combine" in order to obtain something more complex. But it's very unlikely that you will get what you want. My recommendation is the following:

1. Create your human body using a 3D modelling application such as 3DS Max or Maya (they were built for these kind of things)
2. Import your body into Unity3D and animate it there.

Comment: "2nded"  There aren't many alternatives that support so many platforms.  Irrlicht comes to mind but it only supports Windows, Linux, and OS X.  The licensing costs for Unity 3D will be high but compared to the labor cost of rolling your own... it's like a drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is certainly one of the more popular 3D engines, it is rather straight forward to use, hough I am not sure about Kinect Support.

Are there really no other requirements or restrictions?

If you want to develop on Iphone or Android, you will need to do it in Java, Xbox will want you to use C#. PC and Mac is a free for all. If you want to use a Kinect device, you can't make use of a phone.

I personally would suggest, if this is more of a research project, that you just target desktops. You can use a Kinect device and libraries like OpenCV. OpenCV provides a lot of functionality for dealing with camera input. For rendering your 3D scene, either OpenGl or DirectX.

There are a lot of other things you need to think about as well, how do you plan to get geometry data loaded?

Feel free to add more info via comments, and I will do my best to update to help you